# Rails loop failing in javascript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, for-loop

I create Simple deal site. When in index.html.erb loop working only first loop. But it work on show.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing Deal</h1><% @projs.each do |proj| %>

<%= proj.title %><br />

<% if Time.now < proj.end_date %>
  <h3>Days Left:</h3> <div id="countdown" style="width:40%"> <%= distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, proj.end_date)  %> </div>
<% else %>
  <h3> The Project period has passed! </h3>
<% end  %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#countdown').countdown({
      "until" : new Date(<%= date_for_jquery_countdown(proj.end_date) %>)
    });

  })
</script><% end %>
```

Projs_helper.rb**

```
    def date_for_jquery_countdown(date)
    year = date.strftime('%Y')
    month = date.strftime('%-m')
    day = date.strftime('%d')

    "#{year}, #{month}-1, #{day}"

end
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery.plugin
//= require jquery.countdown
```

My browser display index.html.erb only showing first is working, but others not display countdown

[image]

Comment: My model def end_date
  self.start_date + self.funding_period.days
  end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the same id for more than one element in HTML.

You're creating lots of elements with the same id, and only the first one will work.

Use a CSS class instead:

```
 <div class="countdown"
```

...

```
 $('.countdown').countdown(
```

EDIT:

However, you need to set one different value for each iteration, so I would use an ID, but with a counter, for example:

```
<!-- declare a counter here -->
<h1>Listing Deal</h1><% @projs.each do |proj| %>

<%= proj.title %><br />

<% if Time.now < proj.end_date %>
  <h3>Days Left:</h3> <div id="countdown_<$= counter %>" style="width:40%"> <%= distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, proj.end_date)  %> </div>
<% else %>
  <h3> The Project period has passed! </h3>
<% end  %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#countdown_<$= counter %>').countdown({
      "until" : new Date(<%= date_for_jquery_countdown(proj.end_date) %>)
    });

  })
</script>
<!-- assign your counter = counter + 1 here -->
<% end %>
```

Sorry, but I don't know ruby, so I did the comments you would need to change!

Comment: btw, as you need a different value for each element in your iteration, you need to use a counter or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a good practice to have more than one element in a page with the same html id. In your case, all your countdown elements have the same id(#countdown) Change it to a class(And probably move the width:40% to the css file under countdown)

```
<% if Time.now < proj.end_date %>
  <h3>Days Left:</h3> <div class="countdown" style="width:40%"> <%= distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, proj.end_date)  %> </div>
<% else %>
  <h3> The Project period has passed! </h3>
<% end  %>
```

And in your Javascript, use the class

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.countdown').countdown({
      "until" : new Date($(this).text())
    });

  })
</script>
```

Also move the javascript block out of the loop

Comment: however, this isn't going to set the right countdown date for each project - it's going to set all of them to the date for the last project.

Comment: @FaiqAdam: Modified my answer. Move the javascript block out of the loop

Comment: i added class="countdown-<%= proj.id %> thank @Vimsha